# How to output a dynamic table with an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

This has been driving me nuts the past two days.

```
{{:id=>1, :name=>"Brown, James", :completed_at=>"2020-03-01"}=>{:count=>5},
 {:id=>2, :name=>"Allen, John", :completed_at=>"2020-03-01"}=>{:count=>6},
 {:id=>1, :name=>"Brown, James", :completed_at=>"2020-03-03"}=>{:count=>6},
 {:id=>3, :name=>"Davis, Carl", :completed_at=>"2020-03-04"}=>{:count=>10}}
```

I have this data which I got from an ActiveRecord query and mapped in a way where I have a count of tasks done by a user per day. The user basically picks a month and year e.g. March 2020, and it counts the tasks per user from the beginning and end of the month.

What I want to achieve with this is a table that looks like the image I uploaded below:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQzed.png)

I've tried multiple things such as taking the names and dates into a completely separate array and trying to output based on conditionals but I can't seem to make it work. Note that the table headers are dynamic based on the dates given. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please post the code you have so far

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We need to see evidence of your effort toward solving this problem. Also, do not use images to convey important information. Copy, then paste the text into your question formatting it appropriately, without tagging it with "edit" or "update" as we can tell what changed when.

Comment: Your sample data isn't in a normal format, but instead looks like it wasn't gathered correctly. I suspect this is an XY Problem. "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)"
"[XyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can do it in that way (it is just example make it fit to your needs)

```rb
obj = {
  {:id=>1, :name=>"Brown, James", :completed_at=>"2020-03-01"}=>{:count=>5},
  {:id=>2, :name=>"Allen, John", :completed_at=>"2020-03-01"}=>{:count=>6},
  {:id=>1, :name=>"Brown, James", :completed_at=>"2020-03-03"}=>{:count=>6},
  {:id=>3, :name=>"Davis, Carl", :completed_at=>"2020-03-04"}=>{:count=>10}
}
columns = obj.map { |k, _v| k[:completed_at] }.uniq
strokes = obj.map { |k, _v| { id: k[:id], name: k[:name] } }.uniq

result = []

result.push('name')
columns.each do |c|
  result.push(c)
end

strokes.each do |stroke|
  result.push(s[:name])
  columns.each do |column|
    cell = obj.find do |k, _v|
      k[:id] == stroke[:id] && k[:completed_at] == column
    end
    result.push(cell&.last.try(:[], :count))
  end
end
```

And result will be

```rb
[
  "name", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-04", 
  "Brown, James", 5, 6, nil, 
  "Allen, John", 6, nil, nil, 
  "Davis, Carl", nil, nil, 10
]
```

Comment: You just gave me an idea with your code kind sir, I modified it and got just what I needed. I can't thank you enough!